# Getting all the current effective records from a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL database

Table 1 say table1 with fields `(id, name)` 
Records e.g.

```
###############
id |  name
1  |  Chair
2  |  Table
3  |  Bed
###############
```

and Table 2 say table2 with fields `(id, table1_id, date, price)`

```
##############################
id |table1_id| date     |  price
1  |  1  |  2013-09-09  |  500
2  |  1  |  2013-08-09  |  300
3  |  2  |  2013-09-09  |  5100
4  |  2  |  2013-08-09  |  5000
5  |  3  |  2013-09-09  |  10500
################################
```

What I want to achieve is to retrieve all the latest price of items from table 2

Result of SQL should be like

```
##############################
id |table1_id| date     |  price
1  |  1  |  2013-09-09  |  500
3  |  2  |  2013-09-09  |  5100
5  |  3  |  2013-09-09  |  10500
################################
```

I am able to sort them by query

```
SELECT * FROM table2 GROUP BY table1_id ORDER BY date DESC
```

But it seems GROUP BY runs before ORDER BY Clause so the result is not as required
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Comment: What is the 'latest' price if within one date there will be more than 1 records?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo, table is not recording timestamp therefore it may be any one of them. as price does not change frequently this situation will never come

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit the joined entries in the `ON` clause using a subquery, thus, only the newest entries are joined:

```
SELECT t2.id, t1.id, t1.name, t2.date, t2.price 
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 
    ON (t1.id = t2.table1_id 
      AND t2.id = (
        SELECT id 
        FROM table2 
        WHERE table1_id = t1.id 
        ORDER BY table2.date DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    ));
```

Results in:

```
|1|1|Chair|2013-09-09|  500|
----------------------------
|3|2|Table|2013-09-09| 5100|
----------------------------
|5|3|  Bed|2013-09-09|10500|
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery, like this:

```
SELECT 
  table2.id,
  dates_table.max_date,
  dates_table.table1_id,
  table2.price
FROM
  (SELECT 
    MAX(`date`) AS max_date, 
    table1_id
  FROM
    table2
  GROUP BY
    table1_id) AS dates_table
  LEFT JOIN
    table2 ON dates_table.`max_date`=table2.`date`
```

Comment: sorry only one answer can be accepted but it is also working:)